# awakeFromNib() is not working on simulate metric

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nslayoutconstraint, awakefromnib

Hi I have a question about layout.

I use the storyboard to set layout.

[image: I had set on Size of iPhone 4.7-inch]

And I had set an UI Components via the storyboard.

To support iPhone5 or iPhone 6 Plus.. I'm writing code like this.

```
enter//1. called awakeFromNib() 

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()

    //alignment
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    //ImageView Alignment
    profileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(width / 16, width / 16, width / 4 , width / 4)

    //Text Alignment
    postsTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(postsTitleTextLabel.center.x, postsTitleTextLabel.center.y + 50)


}
```

//2. Other ways..

```
 //alignment
       usernameButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       profileImagevView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       commentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       dateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //constraints
    //Vertical
    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-5-[username]-(-2)-[comment]-5-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["username":usernameButton, "comment":commentLabel]))

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-15-[date]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["date":dateLabel]))

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-10-[profile(40)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["profile":profileImagevView]))

    //Horizontal
    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-10-[profile(40)]-13-[comment]-20-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["profile":profileImagevView, "comment":commentLabel]))

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[profile]-13-[username]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["profile":profileImagevView, "username":usernameButton]))

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|[date]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["date":dateLabel]))
```

code here

My question is

**Why this code is not working on iPhone6?** (iPhone5 / 6 Plus is working fine)
-> It happened from set Simulated Metrics?

Answer (score 1):

`awakeFromNib` is not the place to set up UI code. None of the views have been initialized by this point (nil pointers). You should move your UI code to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :)